# Accessing value inside "a" tag , which is inside "li" tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

How do i get a value of a nested tag ?

I want to access the value "MY NAME IS JOHN" using jquery, how do i do that

```
<ul>
    <li id="name_check"><a href="#"> MY NAME IS JOHN </a></li>
</ul>
```

How do i use jquery and the given id of 'li' to access this name .

I tried using jQuery(#name_check).value, but it give "0" as the result on a javascript alert box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
$("#name_check a").text();
```

Note the space between `#name_check` and `a`. That means any `a` tag that is a child (at any level of the DOM) of `#name_check`

Comment: I am actually working with jstree, and if i call what you suggested, then it basically loads the text for this id, and all the children, i just want the name of this id and not the children

Comment: Then you can use `#name_check > a`

Answer (score 2):

You could get the text value with

`$('li#name_check > a').text();`

as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/uanS4/

Comment: For the jstree, with children to this 'li' this is the best option

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = $('#name_check a').html();
```

It's like the selectors you know from css: with the space after the #name_check you say that you want the `<a>` tag inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 var val= $('#name_check a').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#name_check a").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use -

```
$("#name_check").find('a').text(); //recomended
```

the other option is -

```
$("#name_check a").text(); //not recomended
```

but I will suggest you to **avoid** this below one as per jQuery docs find works faster in finding child to specific parent instead of writing in css way

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
<a id="test">test text</a>


alert($("#test").html())
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/Elfego/KUHxn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = jQuery(#name_check a).text()
```

or

```
var a = jQuery(#name_check).find(a).text()
```